# How do I neutralize another hacker?

Tags: watch-dogs-2

I've been targeted in a couple of data hacks and manager to profile the attacker. The game then tells me to neutralize them - but then I got told off for running them over, or shooting at them. To cap it all, they are trying to do the same to me (and the game has kicked them for trying it).

I don't get any quick menu when I press L1, so it does not seem like I can call the cops or hack them another way.

So, what does the game mean by neutralize, and how do you get it done?

Comment: What do you mean by "told off"? Did you fail the neutralization or did you just get penalized?

Comment: I'm not sure if there was a penalty - I probably didn't get the followers reward for the neutralization - I just got a message saying "you're not supposed to kill the other player"

Comment: How can I improve the question Mr Downvoter?

Answer (score 1):

You can neutralize the target with the stun gun or using the takedown

Comment: Ah - thanks about the stun gun. What is "takedown"?

Comment: Ah - I guess you mean a melee attack?

Comment: Yes. The melee attack is the takedown. You can also vault over cover with the other player on the other side